# AngularJS service receiving data from a Chrome Extension content script sometimes won't update view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on a Chromium extension which sends data from a content script to another extension page which runs an Angular app.  Since I separated my app into several controllers relying on a data service, I've run into a bug where sometimes my app's templates will all display correctly but other times it will not.  In this simplified example, my app might display the data value on the page on a run and then not display it after refreshing the page and running the same code.

In the case when the data is *not* displayed, I can still inspect the DataService object at runtime and find the data value to be instantiated correctly.

app.js

```
angular.module('angularApp', [])
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'DataService', 
function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.dataService = dataService;
}]);
```

service.js

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp');
angularApp.service('DataService', function() {
    var data = [];
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
        var messageData = $.extend([], message.data);
        // populate data array based on messageData
    });
};
```

view.html

```
<html ng-app="angularApp">
    <body ng-controller="AppController">
        {{dataService.data}}
    </body>
</html>
```

This seems to be an issue with the asynchronous arrival of the message from the content script, but I'm not sure of the appropriate way to solve this within my Angular service.  An ideal answer would explain what is going on to cause my bug and the best practice to build my service and controllers to work as expected every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller and view are fine. Your service should work if you do this:

```
angular.module('angularApp').service('DataService',['$timeout',
  function($timeout){
    var self = this;
    this.data = [];
    var tmp;
    function handleMessage(){
      //tmp == message.data 
      //populate self.data however..
    }
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender){
      tmp = message.data;
      $timeout(handleMessage);
    });            
}]);
```

The reason it isn't working currently is because the event handler isn't executing in angular's event loop. By doing the data manipulation in a `$timeout` it will force angular to update the view with the data that has changed.

Using `$timeout` essentially has the same effect as `$scope.$apply()` in this scenario